# Is there another expression for "cheat on" or "have an affair"?

Tags: word-choice

Is there another word for "cheating on somebody"? Instead of using " have an affair with somebody", could you help me come up with another word for it ? Can I say " he has a mistress or concubine or lover"?

Comment: Commit adultery?

Comment: You have now added the final sentence. Certainly you can say any of those things.

Comment: Do you need a new word? Having a "mistress" is universally understood I would think, while a "lover" usually implies a partner to whom one is not legally married, but does not necessarily mean there is an affair going on. And "concubine" reeks of a Middle Eastern or Chinese harem, and would only be used in a jocular context,

Comment: There are easily 50.

Comment: Yet another question marked as a 'duplicate' that is not. **Every word is important:** this question does not stipulate 'informal', nor does it stipulate 'humorous'; it also does not *suggest* the answer should ("ideally") pertain to a relationship between an older man and a younger woman. Just because you can shoehorn the foot in doesn't mean the shoe fits.

Answer (score 3):

Phrases in use with the meaning of 'cheating on' somebody include

> **step out (on someone)**
>   to be unfaithful to a spouse or lover.

[step out with. (n.d.) McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. (2002). Retrieved December 8 2015 from http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/step+out+with .]

> **two-time**
>   *tr.v.* two-timed, two-tim·ing, two-times Slang
>   1. To be unfaithful to (a spouse or lover).

[two-time. (n.d.) American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. (2011). Retrieved December 8 2015 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/two-time .]

> **fool around** *informal*
>   4. a. To have a sexual affair with someone who is not one's spouse or partner.

[fooling around. (n.d.) American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. (2011). Retrieved December 8 2015 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fooling+around .]

> **play away from home**  (British & Australian informal)
>   to have sex with someone who is not your usual partner (usually in continuous tenses)

[play away from home. (n.d.) Cambridge Idioms Dictionary, 2nd ed.. (2006). Retrieved December 8 2015 from http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/play+away+from+home .]

Added from a suggestion by [Marv Mills](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/76722/marv-mills) in the comments:

> **have it away**  *(British very informal!)* ...
>   to have sex with someone (often + with ) *She was having it away with her best friend's husband.*

[have it away. (n.d.) Cambridge Idioms Dictionary, 2nd ed.. (2006). Retrieved December 8 2015 from http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+it+away .]

For single words, given an appropriate context,

- deceive
- betray

will both convey the sense of 'cheating on' somebody.

Comment: Also "Having it away [with her]"...

Comment: @MarvMills, thanks, that works well. I got panicky for a minute when I failed to find an external source, but one turned up, so I added your suggestion. If you want to use it in a separate answer, let me know and I'll delete it from mine.

Comment: No probs, it's my gift to you :) But please note, "Having it off" in no way signifies an adulterous relationship- it's just slang for 'having sex' and furthermore has not been used since the 70s or 80s really :) Whereas "having it away" implies some definite hanky panky or monkey business :)

Answer (score 1):

If the affair is secret, you might want to consider ***sneak around [on someone]***

> : to do something without someone's knowledge, especially to engage in romantic relationships: *I suspect her husband has been sneaking around*. *I think his wife was sneaking around on him*. [The American Heritage® Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sneak+around)
>
> *You snuck around with him all summer and never told me* [Game for Trouble](https://books.google.fr/books?id=tTU5AAAAQBAJ&pg=PT155&lpg=PT155&dq=you+snuck+around+with+him+and+never&source=bl&ots=wejliNlnBF&sig=SbKCgLhSt275YpGV8UgQw9wqXNg&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwikjeCK-8vJAhVJ2hoKHd7zBBAQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=you%20snuck%20around%20with%20him%20and%20never&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

Another expression for this is ***having a bit on the side*** … a rather unpleasant term, but still, another option.

*[Example](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/a-bit-on-the-side)*

Answer (score 0):

Cuckold

> noun archaic
>
> 1. the husband of an adulteress, often regarded as an object of derision.
>
> verb
>
> 1. (of a man) make (another man) a cuckold by having a sexual relationship with his wife.

[google.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=cuckold&oq=cuckold&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Sounds like you want the verb form

Comment: *Cuckold* is a very specific sense of a man whose wife/partner is having an affair. Neither is it in modern currency.

Comment: @ws2 I believe it has strong modern currency. I was just reading about "cuckservative" as a new insult in US politics. Aha, http://www.slate.com/blogs/xx_factor/2015/08/13/what_the_rise_of_cuckservative_means_for_republican_politics.html

Answer (score 0):

Consider **another woman**:

> a woman who you have a sexual relationship with when you are married to someone else or are involved in a serious relationship with someone else
>
> *Do you think there’s another woman?*

([Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/unfaithful#unfaithful__1))

Alternatively, consider **play around**:

> If someone who is married or has a partner plays around, they have **sexual relationships with other people**

([Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/play-around))

Also, **unfaithful**:

> having a sexual relationship with someone who is not your husband, wife, or partner
>
> *He had never been unfaithful to her before.*

([Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/unfaithful#unfaithful__1))